Asymptotic fraction and Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem.
Here is the question I am trying to tackle:
Show that for almost every number $x \in [0,1)$ with a decimal expansion $0.a_0a_1a_2 \dots,$ the asymptotic fraction of the $a_i$ that are equal to $7$ is $\frac{1}{10}.$ That is for each $x = 0.a_0a_1a_2 \dots \in [0,1),$ let $$f_7(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\# \{ a_0, \dots, a_n \text{ that are equal to 7}\}}{n}$$ I want to show that $$\mu(\{x | f_7(x) = \frac{1}{10}\}) = 1.$$
Thoughts:
I would let $X = [0,1)$ and consider $T: X \to X$ given by $T(x) = 10 x \pmod{1}.$ this is ergodic with respect to Lebesgue measure. Then I should apply the birkhoff's ergodic theorem to an approprietly chosen indicator function which I guess is $f\circ T$ or $f\circ 
 T^i,$ I am not very sure which one to apply?
If you clarify to me this question, I would appreciate it very much.
Also, I think that the following part $\# \{ a_0, \dots, a_n \text{ that are equal to 7}$ I should take it as my $f \circ T^i,$ am I correct?
Here is the statement of the Birkhoff's ergodic theorem:
Suppose $(X, \mu, T)$ is a probability measure preserving system and $T$ is ergodic w.r.t $\mu.$ Then $\forall f \in L^1(X),$ we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(T^i(x)) = \int_X f d \mu$$ for a.e. $x \in X.$
My question last question is:
The idea in general of the proof in all its details is not fully formulated in my mind, if someone can show me the other details I missed I would appreciate this too much.

Try letting f be the characteristic function of the interval [0.7,0.8).

yeah that is what I was thinking but then I evaluate the integration and then it equals the limit by birkhoff's thm. Right? @HoanNguyễn but how about my other questions?

Regarding your multiple questions, please keep in mind our guideline to ask one question per post.

Elaborate on my comment, let $f=\chi_{[0.7,0.8)}$ the characteristic function of the interval $[0.7,0.8)$.
Then for $x=0.a_0a_1a_2\dots$ ,
$$f(T^ix)=f(0.a_ia_{i+1}a_{i+2}\dots)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } a_i\neq 7,\\
1 &\text{if } a_i = 7,
\end{cases}$$
hence $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)=\#\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1} \text{ that are equal to } 7\}$.
Thus, by the $\mathbf{\text{Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem}}$, for a.e. $x\in [0,1)$,
$$f_7(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\#\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\text{ that are equal to }7\}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)=\int_0^1 fdx=\frac{1}{10}.$$
Here my $f_7$ is a bit different from your $f_7$ above, but I hope you can see that this is not an issue.

what about my remaining questions?

Sorry, I'm not sure which question you are referring to @Intuition . I believe the first 3 question marks (with bold text) are answered above.

ok, let me read the answer carefully, sorry about that :)

I can not see what is the difference between your $f_7$ and my $f_7.$ can you clarify this please?

how will you get the measure 1 of the set given in the question then?

I think the answer to my last question is that we proved it for a.e x in X and hence its measure is 1 as required.

@Intuition My $f_7$ counts from $a_0$ to $a_{n-1}$, while yours counts to $a_n$.

@Intuition yes, a.e. $x\in X$ means that the measure of the set of $x$ that satisfies some desired conditions, here it's $f_7(x)=1/10$, is  $1$.

why you excluded $a_n$ from your $f_7$?

@Intuition to make it fit the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^ix)$ in the statement of Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem.
